Sonarqube 8.9 server configured with Oracle 19c on login keeps loading with error in web.log
Sonarqube version 8.9
Oracle version 19.17
JDK version 11.0.17
OJDBC driver version 8 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.17.0.0/)
Oracle Linux Server 8.6
Server comes up but after login the page keeps loading and there is error in web.log file (attaching the same)

Error from web.log:
  2024.08.28 13:14:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.ProjectsInWarningDaemon] Counting number of projects in warning is not started as there are no projects in this situation.
    2024.08.28 13:14:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.p.PlatformLevelStartup] Running Community Edition
    2024.08.28 13:14:36 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] WebServer is operational
    2024.08.28 13:14:44 ERROR web[AZGYRAK2zPom43M2AAAN][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://172.21.144.61:9000/api/navigation/global
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
    ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column  CASEWHENEXISTS(SELECTPB.UUIDFROMPROJECT_BRANCHESPBWHERENEED_ISSUE_SYNC=:1)THEN:"SYS_B_0"ELSE:"SYS_B_1"END  from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: An identifier or literal is invalid
    ### The error may exist in org.sonar.db.component.BranchMapper
    ### The error may involve org.sonar.db.component.BranchMapper.hasAnyBranchWhereNeedIssueSync
    ### The error occurred while handling results
    ### SQL: select     case when exists     (     select pb.uuid from project_branches pb where need_issue_sync = ?     )     then 1     else 0     end         from dual
    ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column  CASEWHENEXISTS(SELECTPB.UUIDFROMPROJECT_BRANCHESPBWHERENEED_ISSUE_SYNC=:1)THEN:"SYS_B_0"ELSE:"SYS_B_1"END  from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: An identifier or literal is invalid
            at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)
            at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:87)
            at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152)
            at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.hasAnyBranchWhereNeedIssueSync(Unknown Source)
            at org.sonar.db.component.BranchDao.hasAnyBranchWhereNeedIssueSync(BranchDao.java:116)
            at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexSyncProgressChecker.isIssueSyncInProgress(IssueIndexSyncProgressChecker.java:80)
            at org.sonar.server.ui.ws.GlobalAction.writeNeedIssueSync(GlobalAction.java:217)
            at org.sonar.server.ui.ws.GlobalAction.handle(GlobalAction.java:150)
            at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:110)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:84)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SonarLintConnectionFilter.doFilter(SonarLintConnectionFilter.java:66)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:108)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:81)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:68)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:76)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:58)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:66)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
            at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1651)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
            Suppressed: org.sonar.api.utils.text.WriterException: Fail to write JSON
                    at org.sonar.api.utils.text.JsonWriter.rethrow(JsonWriter.java:399)
                    at org.sonar.api.utils.text.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:394)
                    at org.sonar.server.ui.ws.GlobalAction.handle(GlobalAction.java:137)
                    ... 48 common frames omitted
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
                    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:558)
                    at org.sonar.api.utils.text.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:392)
                    ... 49 common frames omitted

I have tried changing multiple JARs, DB connection is getting established and schema is created but getting java.sql.SQLException: An identifier or literal is invalid.
I tried executing following query in SQL Developer and it works fine:
select case when exists(select pb.uuid from project_branches pb where need_issue_sync = '1')
then 1 else 0 end from dual;

